# Difference between random.sample(sample,k) and itertools.combinations(p,r)

Tags: python, random, combinations, python-itertools

Hello I am new to python, and have just started writing basic python scripts. I have decided to write a password generator program. I came across `random.sample()` and `itertools.combinations()` functions. And I would like to know the **difference** between them. I have read the documentation and came to the following conclusion:
1. *random.sample() will return a list of unique combination from the population provided there r no repeated values in the population.*
2. *combinations() will also return a tuple of (p,r) possible combinations where r is the length.* and there was this line,*"Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each combination."* which i didn't understand. I assume it says that input elements must be unique to get unique combinations

So i came to final conclusion that both are same. I would like to know whether i am right or wrong (with explanations pls). Thank you.

Comment: "Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each combination".  print and check the difference in outputs of `list(combinations(lst, 2))` for `lst=[1,2,3,4]` and `lst=[1,2,4,4]`

Comment: I tried this...thanks, understood the meaning. There are 2 4's in lst and even then they r treated as different combination because the position of both is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same, actually they do completely different things. `itertools.combinations()` is a generator - it returns a sequence of **all** combinations from a given set of values. `random.sample()` provides one (randomly selected) combination. Run these two snippets:

```
import random
print(random.sample([1,2,3], 2))
```

and

```
import itertools
for c in itertools.combinations([1,2,3],2):
    print(c)
```

and note the difference.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: `itertools.combinations` does *not* return a generator, it returns an `itertools.combinations` object, which is an *iterator* but not a generator.

Comment: Yes i tried out the snippets and i guess i am able to understand. So is itertools.combinations() is more appropriate for password generation? When i am ran the random() script in a loop. The outputs were repeated, whereas in the documentation it is given that random.sample() returns a unique list of elements from the population. I want to know the reason for this.                                   input code: import random
i =0
while i<4:
    print(random.sample([1,2,3], 2))
    i+=1
Output:    
[1, 3]
[3, 2]
[3, 2]
[2, 3]  *sry i am unable to present it in correct format,will learn.

Comment: You're mixing two things: repeated combinations and repeated elements. `random.sample()` guarantees the **elements** in a returned combinations will not be repeated, so in your example you'll never get `(1,1)` or `(2, 2)`; however it cannot guarantee that subsequent calls won't return the same combination - this is what randomness is about!